# jLabel and jTable conflict

Tags: java, swing, awt

Whenever I add the table under the labels there arises a padding of some sort, I want to make the labels to be equally aligned with table.

```
JPanel availablePackages = new JPanel();
availablePackages.setLayout(new BoxLayout(availablePackages, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
JLabel availablePackagesTitle = new JLabel("Availablee Packages");
availablePackagesTitle.setFont(availablePackagesTitle.getFont().deriveFont(16f));
JLabel availablePackagesContent = new JLabel("<html>Below is a summary of availabal packages. Please choose at least one package to proceed</html>");
availablePackages.add(availablePackagesTitle);
availablePackages.add(availablePackagesContent);
JTable table = new JTable(model)
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
availablePackages.add(scrollPane);
```

[image]

Any ideas how to align them equally?

Comment: Use a GridBagLayout, rather than a BoxLayout

Comment: See [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23100014/java-swing-boxlayout-alignment-issues) as well as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228678/java-swing-boxlayout-ignoring-alignmentx).